# How to notify/alert when the SSH/RDP service is not running in GCE VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, stackdriver

GCP Operation's suite doesnot have a pre built metric to monitor the SSH (Linux) / RDP (Windows) service running in the GCE VM. Also I have tried to find it in GCP Logging but couldn't find any logs about the service running in the OS.

Is there any other way to monitor the health of SSH / RDP Service in GCE VM's ? And to forward an alert if it is not in running state.

Comment: You can create custom metric for your use case as per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#monitoring_create_metric-python)

Comment: @Mahboob Could you provide more details on that , like any sample custom metric

Comment: [this github](https://github.com/mchmarny/custom-metrics) helps you to create custom metric

Answer (score 0):

I updated my answer:

You can use Cloud Logging to monitor status of SSH daemon and connections to it on your VM instances:

1. install  [logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#joint-install) that will send logs to Cloud Logging (formerly Stackdriver):

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh
sudo bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-fluentd
sudo apt-get install -y google-fluentd-catch-all-config
```

2. [edit logging agent configuration](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration) located at `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf` to collect entries from `auth.log` by adding:

```
<source>
  type tail
 
  # Parse the timestamp, but still collect the entire line as 'message'
  format /^(?<message>(?<time>[^ ]*\s*[^ ]* [^ ]*) .*)$/
 
  path /var/log/auth.log
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/auth.log.pos
  read_from_head false
  tag auth
</source>
```

3. restart `google-fluentd` to apply updated configuration:

```
sudo service google-fluentd restart
```

4. go to `Cloud Console` -> `Logging` -> `Logs Explorer` and look for events related to SSH daemon:

[image: logging]

5. [configure alerts](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts); in addition, have a look at the 3rd party examples [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/can-you-alert-on-logs-in-stackdriver-7dfb07f495c0) and
   [here](https://blog.softwaremill.com/gcp-goodies-part-5-stackdriver-logging-and-log-based-alerting-5a10d94d5d4c).

You can use same approach for checking and monitoring RDP on Windows:

1. install  [logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#agent-install-windows)
2. [edit logging agent configuration](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration) located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Stackdriver\LoggingAgent\fluent.conf`
3. restart logging agent
4. go to `Cloud Console` -> `Logging` -> `Logs Explorer` and look for events related to RDP service.
5. [configure alerts](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts)

**EDIT**

In order for the incidents to not close automatically, you can create two metrics:
1st logs termination signal and 2nd that logs SSH startups.
Then you should create an alert that fires when the first one is above zero AND second one is below one.
In that way, incident will last until sshd is started again.

Comment: Where in your answer do you show "How to monitor if a service is running"? Your answer only shows the output from a service not the service state.

Comment: @sergiusz , I have created a log based metric to trigger an alert whenever there is a log - "stopped openssh deamon" in cloud logging . To simulate this behaiour, stopped SSH service and got the alert notification but it is getting resolved automatically as the graph goes back to the normal value.  But alert shouldn't get resolved until SSH service gets started / running state again . How do we monitor the service state ?

Comment: *@Deena Dhayal* have you solved your issue with updated answer?

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza No

Comment: @Sergiusz Rusiecki , I have created alerting policy with two conditions and it should trigger when any of the condition met . But it is triggering an alert & getting resolved automatically without even starting the ssh service.                                                                 Condition 1 -  Violates when: Any logging.googleapis.com/user/ssh-stop stream is above a threshold of 0                                                                     
 Condition 2 - Violates when: Any logging.googleapis.com/user/ssh-start stream is below a threshold of 1

Comment: @Deena Dhayal Have a look at my config: https://imgur.com/a/PAd99w3 this setup sends an alert when SSH is down and doesn't close the incident until I acknowledge it.

Comment: @SergiuszRusiecki I tried with changing the aggregation & period as you mentioned and the alert is not getting resolved but when I start the service it again trigger an new alert for ssh start , it is not resolving old alert .  Also if i simulate again , it is not triggering any alert at all , I presume it is because we set the period as 1 day & aggregator as count .